# How to show on screen keyboard on top of canvas?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I show the on screen keyboard of mobile devices on top of the canvas in Unity3D? My canvas now shrinks in size because of the on screen keyboard, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an inbuilt feature for this you would have to do it manually using OnGUI(). To draw something on top of something else just put the script in the order you want it drawn. That means the last peice of gui script will be ontop.